# Which is fastest compass compiler

Tags: compass-sass

I'm looking for very fast compass compiling app.

So far I have tested:

- Regular terminal compiling- results are about 30+ seconds
- Codekit, so far best but still 10+ seconds compile stylesheets
- Koala app 20+ seconds and didn't quite work with OS X, weird errors not disappearing and had to compile manually each file few times- auto compiling failed
- Compass.app worst of all, took about 1.5 minutes to compile stylesheets with huge demands of resources

Comment: Based on your question, the answer is Codekit.  But if you are asking us to find *other* compilers, your question is off-topic.

Comment: However, this question could be a good fit for the "software recommendations" site.  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What about node-sass for sass compiling and bournoun as mixin library. For sprite generating you can use spritesmith or other decision. All tasks you can combine via gulp or other build system. To be honest, compass have only ruby gem, and ruby works not so fast as C++.